# Windows 8 Metro open website / mailto C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm pretty confused. How do I open a website in the webbrowser from my metro app? And how can I open the default mail application?

In WPF on W7 I would just ran

```
Process.Start("mailto://whatever");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do understand using Process.Start("mailto://whatever") is the incorrect way to do it to begin with right?  That only works if the user defined a default mail program.  You should continue to be able to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Metro apps in Windows 8 do not support `Process.Start`. It does not exist on the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

A metro application cannot launch another metro app directly.

However, there are two ways to launch apps. You can launch apps through file association or through protocol handlers (`Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` and `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync`)

Both of these should solve your problem.

Examples and documentation live out on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx

Also look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779672.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://verysoftware.co.uk"));`

Comment: Insert "await" at beginning of the Launcher.LaunchUriAsync code-line to get rid of the Visual Studio warning.